# how to cast LP_LP_c_longlong instance from pointer to LP_c_longlong

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, ctypes

I am using python rtree module to find the nearest city by lat,lon. But on Nginx server after few requests I am getting following error.

It works well on apache but giving argument error on ngix

```
File "/home/ubuntu/core/greedy/utilities.py", line 88, in current_location
    city = GeoLocation.CityByLatLong(location[0], location[1], idx)

  File "/home/ubuntu/core/greedy/apps/geolocations/models.py", line 13, in CityByLatLong
    near_list = idx.nearest((latitude, longitude), 1, objects=False)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rtree/index.py", line 567, in nearest
    p_num_results)

ArgumentError: argument 5: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_c_longlong instance instead of pointer to LP_c_longlong
```